# Description: Connection refused while doing jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I got an error  while run the unit test in jasmine by using `ng test` command.

I have configured everything correctly, because previously it has been works well. i don't know what why suddenly its through this error.

### in browser :

`Description: Connection refused`.

### in command prompt:

```
12 02 2018 12:24:54.858:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost
:9876/
12 02 2018 12:24:54.890:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.2.0 server started at http://loca
lhost:9876/
12 02 2018 12:24:54.890:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited
 concurrency
12 02 2018 12:24:55.780:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
12 02 2018 12:25:55.781:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, k
illing.
12 02 2018 12:25:56.373:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
12 02 2018 12:26:56.377:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, k
illing.
12 02 2018 12:26:56.976:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).
12 02 2018 12:27:57.008:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, k
illing.
12 02 2018 12:27:57.455:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (timeout). Givin
g up.
```

Comment: clean the `npm cache` and reinstall the node_modules

Comment: @Aravind `npm cahce` have done. But reinstall `node-modules` is a big process.  Also I know 100% this issue not related with `node-modules`.

Comment: I had this issue and i did the above one it fixed my issue

Comment: Oh! okay i'll do this. thanks mate. let you know once i reinstall the node modules.

Comment: ok cool. try out update if it doesn't help

Comment: @Aravind See my answer. this issue is related with proxy. I don't know what   is the exact problem. But this time it solved for me.

Comment: Ok. Great. that you fixed it

Comment: @Aravind Yeah, thanks for your help mate.

Comment: @Aravind any idea about this problem?https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5116

Comment: nope. it seems that the other issue is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by enable `Automatically detect settings` of proxy settings in IE browser. But I don't know why it need to do this? if anyone know what is the exact problem and solution, then please upgrade this answer as well.